# Nativescript VueJS - how to enable and disable a button in axios

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

This is my code:

```
<Button text="Login" @tap="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-20" :isEnabled="isTappable" />


submit(event) {
                this.isTappable = false;
                let eventListener = this.isTappable;
                axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/api/authenticate/login',
                    data: {
                        username: 'test',
                        password: "12345"
                    }
                }).then(function(response){
                    eventListener = true;
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                    eventListener = true;
                }).finally(function(){
                    eventListener = true;
                    console.log("eventListener: "+eventListener);
                });
            }
```

I noticed that the button disables, but it doesnt enable back. Any wrong stuff that I did here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with your promise functions(then, catch, finally) to keep the scope of `this` that is referencing to the vue object, then inside of your `finally` function u can do reference to the `isTappable` property using `this`, should be so:

```
<Button text="Login" @tap="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-20" :isEnabled="isTappable" />


submit(event) {
  this.isTappable = false;
  let eventListener = this.isTappable;
  axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/api/authenticate/login',
      data: {
          username: 'test',
          password: "12345"
      }
  }).then((response) => {
      eventListener = true;
  }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      eventListener = true;
  }).finally(() => {
      this.isTappable = true;
      eventListener = true;
      console.log("eventListener: "+eventListener);
  });
}
```

Comment: wow, this totally works! So all this time i should be using arrow function?? haha! Noob here! Thanks much! :)

Comment: just if the use case is required, thinking in  the scope of `this`. sometimes can't be necessary.